# Need suggestion on with MS Graph Rest API url

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I kinda need to suggestion on picking the accurate MSGraph url between below 2 urls.

1. [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{EmailAddress}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BEmailAddress%7D).
2. [https://graph.windows.net/{TenantID}/users?$filter=userPrincipalName%20eq%20'{EmailAddress}'&api-version=1.6](https://graph.windows.net/%7BTenantID%7D/users?$filter=userPrincipalName%20eq%20%27%7BEmailAddress%7D%27&api-version=1.6)

**More details on my situation**:
I need to resolve the **UserName** and **ObjectID** from MS Graph Rest api using EmailAddress. I have 100s of EmailAddress that I need to resolve **UserName** and **ObjectID** for. I was using below which is working fine for most of the time. But lastnight i realized it is not returning valid  response for 2 users.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/")
};
string URI = $"/v1.0/users/{EmailAddress}";
```

Then I realized, below rest API url is retuning accurate response for the missing users as comared to above url

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/")
};
string URI = $"/{TenantID}/users?$filter=userPrincipalName%20eq%20'{EmailAddress}'&api-version=1.6";
```

Comment: It looks like inconsistency in graph API. I would try contacting MS support (report a bug maybe)? Are the two users the first API does not return data for, somehow special? What error do you get?

Comment: @Vinny, is your issue resolved, or can you please share the error message which your getting for those 2-email id's. Thanks

Comment: Hello All,
The issue still stands unresolved.  I reached out to Graph team and they are looking into the anomaly. However, using Uri "https://graph.windows.net", I am getting accurate response.